# Upload a file with year and month in jsp. And get year ,month ,check box value and file in controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a jsp file which uploads a file and contains two dropdowns which selects year and month and a check box. I want these values in controller after submitting. I am using java spring MVC framework. I know that file type should be sent using post method but how can I use other values.?

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="sp" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Upload File</title>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap.css" />"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/bootstrap.min.css" />"  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/payslip-style.css" />" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action ="verifyFile" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">
     <select class="form-control" id="dd1" name="selectYear" >
      <option value="" label="Select Year"/>
       <c:forEach var="year" items="${years}">
        <option value="${year}"><c:out value="${year}"></c:out>
        </option>
       </c:forEach>
                </select>
               </div>
    <div class="dropdown dropdown-inline">
     <select  class="form-control" id="dd2" name="dd2">
      <option value="" label="select Month"/>
       <c:forEach items="${monthsList}" var="months">
        <option value="${months}"><c:out value="${months}"></c:out>
        </option>
       </c:forEach>
                 </select>
                </div><br/><br/>
    <div class="upload-file">
     <b>Header :</b><input type="checkbox" name="header"></input><br/><br/>
     <label class="btn btn-default btn-file">
        Browse File  <input type="file" name="file" style="display: none;" accept=".csv" id="f1" ></input>
     </label>
     <label><span class='label label-info' id="upload-file-info"></span></label><br/><br/>
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="Upload" value="Upload" onclick="validate();"></input>
     <input class="btn btn-primary" type="reset" name="Reset"></input><br/><br/>
    </div>
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that this forms method is POST.

```
<form action ="verifyFile" id="myform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
```

Then create a method for this post in your controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/verifyFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String addStudent(@RequestParam("dd1") String dd1, @RequestParam("dd2") String dd2,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

   }
```

Comment: It is giving 'Required String parameter 'dd1' is not present' error.

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="dd1" name="selectYear" > Name should not be selectYear it should be dd1.

Comment: Same error I got.Required String parameter 'selectYear' is not present.